# destructor execution order in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, destructor

I have some doubts about the result of the following snippet. Thank you in advance!
[image]
why isn't the B1 destructor called? In my opinion, "Dest B" should display ahead of "Dest A"
Any explanation would be appreciated.

```
class A1 {
    public:
        A1() { cout << "Const A" << endl; }
        ~A1() { cout << "Dest A" << endl; }
        virtual const char* ClassName() const{ return ("A"); }
};

class B1:public A1 {
    public:
        B1() { cout << "Const B" << endl; }
        ~B1() { cout << "Dest B" << endl; }
        virtual const char* ClassName() const { return ("B"); }
};

void foo1(A1 *a1)
{
    cout << "foo1 has been passed an object of class " << a1->ClassName() << endl;
    delete a1;
}


int main()
{
    B1 *b1 = new B1;
    foo1(b1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are your "doubts"? What is your question?

Comment: The code you have shown us does not invoke any destructor, and it does not match the output you shown. It doesn't even compile, come to think of it.

Comment: Sorry for my bad in editing. Now the question is edited correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your class `A1` has non-virtual destructor, your `delete a1` produces undefined behavior. It is illegal to apply `delete` to a pointer of type `A1 *` when the pointer actually points to a `B1` object, unless class `A1` has virtual destructor.

What you observe is just a specific manifestation of undefined behavior.

Declare `A1`'s destructor as `virtual` and you should start observing the proper behavior.